# When $G_1\ast_A G_2=1$?

Tags: group-theory

Is the following possible?

$f_1\colon A\to G_1$ and $f_2\colon A\to G_2$ are group homomorphisms and $G_1\ast_A G_2=1$ and  neither $f_1$ nor $f_2$ are surjective.

Comment: Is $*_A$ the free product with amalgamation?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: This emphasizes what I regard as an error in some treatments of free products with amalgamation. The notation $G_1 *_A G_2$ should **only** be used when $A$ is isomorphically identified with a subgroup $A_1 \subset G_1$ and with a subgroup $A_2 \subset G_2$. Otherwise it is **not** a free product with amalgamation. For instance the wikipedia entry on amalgamated free products is incorrect in omitting this assumption.

Comment: There is perfectly good terminology available for the general case where the maps $A \to A_1$, $A \to A_2$ are not assumed to be isomorphisms: a **pushout**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be simple groups with non-trivial proper subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$, let $A=H_1\times H_2$, and let $f_1(x,y)=x$, $f_2(x,y)=y$.